# How to add multiple objects to MoveIt Planning Scene?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to add multiple objects to MoveIt planning scene. Using the Move Group C++ API, I do:

```
moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;
moveit_msgs::CollisionObject co, co2;

..
..
Fill in the fields of moveit_msgs co & co2
```

..
..

```
co.operation = co.ADD;
co2.operation=co2.ADD;

std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> collision_objects;
collision_objects.push_back(co);
collision_objects.push_back(co2) ;

ROS_INFO("Add an object into the world");
planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_objects);

sleep(2.0);
```

When I run it, only one collision object appears i.e. co2 .

I can not figure out what am I missing. Please help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244889/how-to-add-multiple-objects-to-moveit-planning-scene?/) by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2016-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Rohin,

Are you assigning unique id's to the CollisionObjects? Looking at the [message type](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/CollisionObject.html) we can see that for the ADD operation, the CollisionObject information will be replaced if the object (with the id string as an identifier) is already present in the planningScene.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) on 2016-10-03**:
Yeah...

I was doing

co.header.frame_id = group.getPlanningFrame();
co2.header.frame_id = group.getPlanningFrame();

How should I assign different ID's?

**Comment by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) on 2016-10-03**:
Thanks! That solved it!